# Confirmation in Spring boot

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring-security, config

I need to have access to search option for guests, registered users and admin. However when I try to use search button as guest I get redirect to login. With registered user and admin everything works correctly

```
                <form th:action="@{/currency/search}" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-4 md-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input name="query" class="form-control my-2 my-lg-0 md-3" type="search" placeholder="Search currency" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I tried to change SecurityConfig to give access to all users of the service

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/currency/sort").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","USER")
                .requestMatchers("/login", "/register", "/currency", "/currency/search**","/currency?success", "/currency/{currencyId}/exchange-rate","/register/**", "/css/**", "/js/**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/currency")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                        .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                        .permitAll()
                ).logout(
                        logout -> logout
                                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll()
                );

        return http.build();
    }
```

here is my getmapping:

```
    @GetMapping("/currency/search")
    public String searchCurrency(@RequestParam(value = "query") String query, Model model) {
        try {
            List<CurrencyDto> currencies = currencyService.searchCurrency(query);
            model.addAttribute("currencies", currencies);

        } catch (DataNotFoundException e) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", e.getMessage());
        }
        return "userview/currencies-list";
    }
```

and I`m not sure if that useful but also my service and repository code:

````
    @Override
    public List<CurrencyDto> searchCurrency(String query) {
        List<Currency> currencies = currencyRepository.searchCurrency(query);
        if (currencies.isEmpty()) {
            throw new DataNotFoundException("Please enter right currency");
        }
        return currencies.stream()
                .map(currency -> mapToCurrencyDto(currency))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }```
repository
````

@Query("SELECT c FROM Currency c WHERE LOWER(c.title) LIKE CONCAT('%', LOWER(:query), '%')")
List searchCurrency(String query);